# Derivation of GLS coefficients in simple regression

Tags: mathematical-statistics, regression-coefficients, generalized-least-squares

Let $y_t = a + bX_t + u_t $, where $t = 1...n, X$ is not random and $x_t \neq x_s$ for $s \neq t$). $E(u_t) = 0, E(u_tu_s) = 0 $ and $ E(u_t^2) = w_t^2$ with $w_t>0$.

How do we derive GLS coefficients for simple regression? I know how to do it in general, but it's not clear to me how to derive it in case of simple regression

Comment: How does $u_t$ enter into the regression model?

Comment: @MichaelChernick Now updated version is correct.

Comment: Instead of OLS, use "WLS" ("weighted least squares"), i.e., $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{w_i^2}(y_i - a_t - b_tX_t)^2$$